# The following C++ Code relate to pointer and reference

Tags: c++

I have seen this code

```
  void path(
    const char * p);
  » more...

void path(
    const std::string & p);
  » more...
```

Can I do the following modification, basically reversing the * and &.

```
void path(
    const char & p);
  » more...

void path(
    const std::string * p);
  » more...
```

Comment: the syntax is ok in both cases so yes you can but the meaning is completely different. check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: Read a good C++ programming book. We don't have hours to explain the issues of C++ (which is a difficult programming language, so take many hours to learn it).

Comment: If you need to change the argument itself in the function, you need void path(char *& p)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Good comment but I'd say C++ is a rich language rather than difficult

Comment: @lilzz: _"Can I…?"_ -- Have you tried it?

Comment: and in C++11, you would prefer `void path(string&& p)`

Answer (score 3):

The first is passing an array of characters as a pointer to the first one. This is how strings are conventionally handled in C, and you sometimes see it in C++ due to the common heritage of the two languages. While you *could* pass a reference and carefully document that it's actually supposed to be an array, it would be confusing to anyone used to that convention.

The second is passing a single object by reference. While you *could* emulate the reference with a pointer, this would be (mildly) confusing to anyone used to the reference semantics of C++.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand what the function is trying to do before changing.

Lets see what happens when you change `void path(const char * p);` to `void path(const char &p);`

Probably the reason a `char *` is passed could be that the function needs to access an array of characters. And if you change the parameter to `char &p`, then the function only accepts a `char` by reference.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can. but you must be careful with the use of `.` and `->` in these function

and keep in mind that the meaning compelitly changes